# Flex SWC missing MovieClip contents

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, air, flex4

I have a Flex Mobile Project. I also have an FLA where I have a bunch of symbols that are linked to code. The FLA exports a SWC into the libs folder of the Flex project. This Flex project compiles into an iOS  app, so I can't embed a SWF or do any SWF loading (iOS won't run SWFs with code in them).

All the sudden, my FLA assets seem to missing in runtime.

I wasn't having an issue with this earlier today. Symbols were new'ing up just fine and were connected to their FLA code. All the sudden, it stopped working and I have NO IDEA what could have changed.

Any insight or help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

Well, I figured out the issue, but I'd like to figure out a way to make it more ideal.

To clarify, here is the situation a little better explained.
Assets.fla - Symbol "WoodMain" with "Export for ActionScript" set to a classpath of:

```
 app.soundboard.theme.wood.main.WoodMain
```

On publish, it generates a .SWC into the libs folder of the Flex app. It is there and up to date. I've tested by deleting it and republishing.
Then, in my Flex project, I do this:

```
 var main:WoodMain = new WoodMain();
 container.addChild(main);
 main.gotoAndStop('animateIn');
```

Apparently before, "WoodMain" wasn't actually an ActionScript file, which is why it was working. If I change the "Export for ActionScript" to "TestMain" and give it the base class of:

```
 app.soundboard.theme.wood.main.WoodMain
```

and then instantiate "TestMain" instead, then it works. So, it seems if Flex actually has the symbol's class in the classpath, it uses it's classpath prior to referencing the SWC, thus no symbol data gets attached to the code. Is there a way to change this, or alternatively, is there a way to have the SWC be in a different ApplicationDomain where I can access the class?

Comment: "All the sudden, my FLA assets seem to missing in runtime." What does All of a Sudden mean?  It was working, but now it isn't?  Or did something else change?  What does it mean that symbols were "newing up"?  How were you creating the symbols?  Can you provide some code?  Can you provide the full error text?

Comment: All of the sudden. I said "I wasn't having an issue with this earlier today." This same method was working. "newing up" means "instantiate". I have an FLA which has "Export for Actionscript" with as "TestClass," then in my Flex code, I have "var test = new TestClass()", "test.gotoAndPlay('animateIn')" and get the error "Frame label animateIn not found in scene animateIn."

Comment: ArgumentError: Error #2109: Frame label animateIn not found in scene animateIn. at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()